# msbuild log output broken

Tags: visual-studio, logging, msbuild

When building a Visual Studio solution with MSBuild we noticed that the resulting log output is somehow mixed up:

```
6>foo.cpp(819): warning C4100: "param1": unreferenced formal parameterbar.cpp(388): warning C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\src\myproject.vcxproj]

         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(2254): note: see declaration of "sscanf"foo.cpp(819): warning C4100: "param2": unreferenced formal parameter
```

To me it looks similar as when multiple threads are writing to the file without proper synchronization. Note, however, that the build order number (6 in this case) appears only once. The lines around this excerpt look normal but similar errors appear in the log. We can reproduce similar issues with each build. The issue appears on stdout as well as in the logfile.

msbuild is called with these parameters:

```
/m /p:Configuration=Release /t:rebuild /nr:false /FileLogger /Verbosity:normal /ds solution.sln
```

The version used is 14.0.25420.1

This issue causes problems when parsing the log for statistics about compiler errors and warnings. Any ideas what might cause it?

---

**EDIT**

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Create a new Visual Studio project (I chose a console application) with SDL checks disabled (C4996 should be a warning, not an error)
2. Change configuration to Release and platform to x86 (in x64 Warning C4456 is not triggered somehow?)
3. Set Warning Level to 4 (/W4)
4. Enable Multi-processor Compilation (/MP)
5. Add a new file to the project with the following content:

   ```
   #include <stdafx.h>

   #include <cstdio>
   #include <iostream>

   void foo()
   {
       int a = 42;

       {
           int a = 0;

           std::cout << a << std::endl;
       }
   }

   void bar()
   {
       char buffer[50];
       int a = 40;
       int b = 2;
       sprintf(buffer, "%d plus %d is %d", a, b, a + b);

       std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
   }
   ```
6. Create a large number of copies of this file and add all of them to the project. It looks like the more files you add the more likely the issue arises. I successfully reproduced the issue with 100 files.
7. Compile the project. It will fail with a lot of LNK2005 errors because of the multiple symbol definitions, but this is not relevant here.
8. See the number of warnings change between two rebuilds. Should be three times the number of files you added but often is less. This is caused by the issue described above.

Comment: Would you please share me a sample and some detailed steps to reproduce this issue? According to the error, it seems the error comes from the `foo.cpp`  not MSBuild. And if create a new blank project and build with your build command line, it work fine. So you can also create a new blank project, check if it still have this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I tried to reproduce the issue with a new project. It did not appear. With the original solution the issue does not always appear at the same line, not even the same file nor project. But it does appear consistently somewhere within the solution. I suspect it having something to do with building multiple files/projects in parallel. Do you have any ideas what I could try to reproduce the issue with a project I could then post here?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I was finally able to reproduce the issue. I will update my question with the details.